# DateDiff SQL Server Problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

Could some one please explain this to me as I am a touch confused as to why this is happening? Basically what I would like to know is why there is a difference between Sundays date and every other day of this week in weeks from the year 0. If that makes sense!

I tried setting the date first but this had no effect. Surely Monday – Sunday of this week should all have the same difference in weeks from the year zero?

```
Set Datefirst 1
Select DateName(dw,0) --Monday
Select DateDiff(week, 0, '20091109')--Monday: Difference 5732
Select DateDiff(week, 0, '20091114')--Saturday: Difference 5732
Select DateDiff(week, 0, '20091115')--Sunday: Difference 5733
```

What makes this even more bizarre is if you take the same two dates and date diff them you get one week for the one and 6 days for the other.  Am I missing something here?

```
Select DateDiff(dd,'20091109','20091115')--6 Days difference
Select DateDiff(ww,'20091109','20091115')--1 Week difference
```

I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

Sunday is considered the first day of the week in a number of countries.

Comment: I think you're on to something... Select DateDiff(wk,'20091108','20091114') returns 0.

Comment: This is exactly the reason.  SQL Server considers the calendar week to be Sunday through Saturday in most setups.

Comment: As an addendum, you can set what day of the week SQL Server considers to be the first day of the week with a SET DATEFIRST command.  followed by a 1 (Monday) through 7 (Sunday).  In the default installation, this is a 7 (Sunday)

Comment: -1 because "Select DateDiff(week,'20091109','20091115')" is independant of SET DATEFIRST. Also, the other code stays the same whatever you put as the DATEFIRST amount

Comment: So I get -1 because of someone else's comment? Thanks, Craig!

Comment: @Craig - You're right but why the downvote for Randolph when you disagreed with BBlake's suggestion?  In addition, NOBODY explicitly claimed that datefirst impacted datediff...

Answer (score 3):

All the datediff functions do is count the number of date ***boundarys*** between the two datetime arguments passed to it.  So if a week is defined to start Sunday, then the week *boundary* is midnight Sunday Morning.

So, From 11:59 Saturday night to 00:01 am Sunday Morning, will be the ***same*** `datediff(week, x, y)` as from 00:01 Sunday to 11:59 PM Saturday Night - 13 days later.

```
 x ------------------------------x    ==> 1 week diff
| Su M T W T F S | Su M T W T F S |
|                |                |
                x-x                   ==> Also 1 week diff
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are facing is the boundary dates. Are they inclusive?

```
Select DateDiff(dd,'20091109','20091115')--6 Days difference
Select DateDiff(dd,'20091109','20091116')--7 Days difference
```

**DateDiff** - Returns the number of date and time boundaries crossed between two specified dates. (Books Online Definition)

Answer (score 1):

If you Set Datefirst = 1, Monday is the first day of the week, and the week calculations would use MOD 7 for number of days in the week and /7 for week count, in which sunday would be used as 1, and the others FLOORed to 0.